# random.longs(ARRAY_SIZE, 0, 100000) returns long stream and I want to convert this stream into Long Array. how it can be done?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, java-8, java-stream

I want to generate a stream of long number, so I used random function and then converted that stream into array by using toArray(). but this array is generated in long[], but I want in Long[]. so how it can be done

```
Long[] array1 = new Long[1000000];

Random random = new Random();

array1 = random.longs(ARRAY_SIZE, 0, 100000).toArray();
```

Type mismatch: cannot convert from long[] to Long[]

Comment: *Why* do you need a boxed `Long` array? This is going to be far less efficient, and represents a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.  But why use a Long[] instead of a primitive array of long[]?  Object wrappers of primitive types have more overhead.  And if you assign them to a primitive type, unboxing is required for conversion.

```java
      Long[] array1 = new Long[ARRAY_SIZE];

      Random random = new Random();
      array1 = random.longs(ARRAY_SIZE, 0, 100000).boxed().toArray(Long[]::new);
```

Comment: It not works. it's showing a error of "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to Long[]". can't use primitive long[ ] as I have to follow requirements. please suggest

Comment: I can't explain it.  It works fine for me.  Please recheck your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`Random::longs` returns a `LongStream`. So assuming you want to collect it into array `Long[]`, then this should help:

```
Long[] array = random.longs(ARRAY_SIZE, 0, 100000)
                     .boxed()
                     .toArray(Long[]::new);
```

---

You can check the approach on a shorter stream:

```
Long[] array = LongStream.range(0, 10)
                         .boxed()
                         .toArray(Long[]::new);

for (Long l : array){
    System.out.println(l);
}
```